# Excel error – command sending fails

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2007

Everytime I double click .xls file I get error window: "There was a problem sending the command to the program".  There is no problem if I open the file by “File-Open” command..
I tried to copy and remove these files on another PC, but still the same…
Also I verified DDE option, but it was unchecked basically.
The problem still unresolved. Any recommends?

Comment: Any luck trying [this](http://www.askvg.com/fix-there-was-a-problem-sending-the-command-to-the-program-error-message-in-windows/)?

Comment: [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA)